# CPACK embed text files

Tags: macros, installation, cmake, customization, cpack

I want to distribute a gzipped tarball containing a program binary.
No problem making a package containing the binary plus additional script/man files because these are files I install with CMake INSTALL command during a source installation.

While the need for such a functionality seems quite obvious to me, I didn't find a way to include text files in CPack tarball packages.
Here is an example of the final tarball I'd like to get:

```
myprogram-1.0.0rc-Darwin-i386/
├── LICENSE <- not installed by CMake
├── INSTALL <- not installed by CMake
├── README  <- not installed by CMake
├── bin
│   └── myprogram
└── share
    └── myprogram
        └── man
            └── man1
                └── myprogram.1
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Why wouldn't you add additional INSTALL commands for those files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `install` too with `FILES` or `DIRECTORY` option.

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.txt DESTINATION .)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it won't do it because this will install the README file even when doing a make install.

Comment: In the end, what's the way to use this command only if "make package" is called?

Comment: `install` commands are only called when invoking `make package` or `cpack` (which is the way I recommend since for some Generators, there is no makefile but still a packaging step). <edit>I didn't noticed the `make install` step you mentioned… maybe you can add an extra option "PACKAGING" and only set it to `ON` when you want effective packaging? From my point of view, `make install` and `cpack`/`make package` shouldn't be invoked at the same time.

Comment: For the "PACKAGING" boolean, that's the workaround I came up to but it's no very satisfying because you can still invoke `make package` while PACKAGING is to OFF and generate a wrong package. Besides, I'm not sure I understand you but `make install` and `make package` are not invoked at the same time (I do not invoke `make install package` if that's what you mean). But I'd like CMake to include the README when I'm doing a package and not when I'm installing it (operations that can be done with several week of interval).